# h5py: error when slicing a h5py dataset

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, h5py

**[update: the issue has been solved. see the end for the solution]**

I am trying to slice a h5py dataset but only get an error here

```
In[76]: dataset['traindata']
Out[76]: <HDF5 dataset "traindata": shape (100, 50), type "<f4">

In[76]: dataset['traindata'][0, 0:10]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
SystemError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-77-4033a3d41a81> in <module>()
----> 1 dataset['traindata'][0, 0:10]

E:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\h5py\_hl\dataset.pyc in __getitem__(self, args)
    437         mspace = h5s.create_simple(mshape)
    438         fspace = selection._id
--> 439         self.id.read(mspace, fspace, arr, mtype)
    440 
    441         # Patch up the output for NumPy

SystemError: error return without exception set
```

But when I slice another dataset in the same group, it seems to work fine

```
In[74]: dataset['trainlabel']
Out[74]: <HDF5 dataset "trainlabel": shape (1, 50), type "<i4">

In[75]: dataset['trainlabel'][0, 0:10]
Out[75]: array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
```

I don't quite understand what's wrong with `dataset['trainlabel']`.

Has anyone ran into this before? Thanks.

P.S. `dataset` is read from a v7.3 .mat file. "traindata" is originally a single precision matrix and "trainlabel" an int32 vector in the .mat file.

**[Solution:]** Overwrite the existing h5py lib (shipped with Anaconda) by a pre-built version available from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#h5py .

Comment: What did you tag `Matlab`?

Comment: @Dan the data is read from a v7.3 matlab file, so I guess some matlab guy might have an idea...

Comment: What do you get from `dataset['traindata'].value`?  Can you slice that?

Comment: @askewchan only get the same error...

Comment: So it's not a slicing error, just an accessing error it seems.  Can you access it fine from matlab?

Comment: @askewchan just solved the issue by manually install a pre-built h5py package from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#h5py . Looks like something is wrong with the h5py package shipped with Anaconda. Thanks, buddy!

Comment: You should add your solution as an answer and then accept it after the 48 hours cooldown period, so it won't be listed as `UNANSWERED`